# make a df out of a df of lists in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

Below is a df that I have in pandas ipython. I would like to count the objects in each list and put the resulting count into a df.['sponsor_id', 'list_count_int']

```
     sponsor_id
7       [s2474-112, s1543-112, s1262-112, s3676-112, s...
11      [s130-110, s169-110, s589-110, s134-110, s3062...
66      [s918-112, s946-112, s3326-112, s2007-112, s33...
116     [s79-112, s1302-112, s3304-112, s175-112, s76-...
136     [s1619-112, s2475-112, s2507-112, s328-112, s2...
.
.
.
```

Below is the code that I have. I am trying to use a for loop.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f, names=['date','bill_id','sponsor_id']) for f in glob.glob('/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/df/s11?_s_b')))

df.groupby('sponsor_id').apply(lambda x: list(x['bill_id']))



#this is the code for my for loop
df_new = df['sponsor_id'].astype('list').map(lambda x: sum(y for y in ['sponsor_id']))
```

I'm getting a very long error message. Here is the end of it:

```
/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in _astype(self, dtype, copy, raise_on_error, values, klass, mgr, **kwargs)
    443 
    444         # astype processing
--> 445         dtype = np.dtype(dtype)
    446         if self.dtype == dtype:
    447             if copy:

TypeError: data type "list" not understood
```

Comment: I think you can use `df['count'] = df['sponsor_id'].apply(len)`

Comment: Tried 

    df1 = df['sponsor_id'].apply(len)

get error:

    TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int64' has no len()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have `int` values in column `sponsor_id`. So you can [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) `len` only for values of type `list`. Other values (`int`) are set to `1`:

```
print df
                                     sponsor_id
0  [s2474-112, s1543-112, s1262-112, s3676-112]
1                          [s130-110, s169-110]
2                                           102

df['count'] = df['sponsor_id'].apply(lambda x: len(x) if isinstance(x, list) else 1) 
print df
                                     sponsor_id  count
0  [s2474-112, s1543-112, s1262-112, s3676-112]      4
1                          [s130-110, s169-110]      2
2                                           102      1
```

Comment: I am working on applying your code. I think one problem is that  sponsor_id is the column on the far left. The list does not actually have a column header. The list is actually a list of bill ids.

Comment: So you can create it: `df['new'] = df.groupby('sponsor_id').apply(lambda x: list(x['bill_id']))` and then change `sponsor_id` to `new` in my solution.
`

Comment: That nailed it! Thanks for the help!